# Immutable JS: Set value of map inside map

Tags: immutable.js

I have Immutable like this

```
Immutable.Map({
    name: action.data.name,
    avatarUrl: action.data.up,
    profileUrl: action.data.upl,
    id: action.data.uid,
    role: Immutable.fromJS(action.data.r),
    color: Immutable.Map({
      initial: '#00FF00',
    })
});
```

All I want is to check if a value corresponding to a key exists inside `color map`, then change it. If it does not exist then add a new key inside `color map` with the new value like this:

```
Immutable.Map({
    name: action.data.name,
    avatarUrl: action.data.up,
    profileUrl: action.data.upl,
    id: action.data.uid,
    role: Immutable.fromJS(action.data.r),
    color: Immutable.Map({
      initial: '#00FF00',
      c-0: '#000000',
      7: '#0000FF'
    })
});
```

What I tried is this, but it aint working and adds keys anywhere.

```
return state.setIn(state.getIn('color', action.thread_id), action.code);
```

thread_id is the key like 'c-0' or '7' and code contains the value to be added or updated against the key

**Update 1**
When adding keys like 'c-0' and 'c-1', and '7' and '8', it adds inside the map like

```
Immutable.Map({
    name: action.data.name,
    avatarUrl: action.data.up,
    profileUrl: action.data.upl,
    id: action.data.uid,
    role: Immutable.fromJS(action.data.r),
    c: Immutable.Map({
      -: Immutable.Map({
        0: '#00F0F0',
        1: '#0000F0',
      })
    })
    7: '#FFFF00',
    8: '#00FFFF',
    color: Immutable.Map({
      initial: '#00FF00'
    })
});
```

Comment: Using `state.getIn(['color', 'initial'])`, i'm not able to access the value of key initial. Any help would be apprieciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me: `return state.setIn(['color', action.thread_id], action.code);`